# too long to create an entity manager-- it hangs

Tags: java, spring, jpa, intellij-idea

- SpringBatch+JPA+createEntityManager hangs and then work after
  sometime

When we run the job locally through Intellij it works fine.

When we deploy the same code on the server and run it on the server it works fine **once**, but if we try to *run the same job again immediately*, it **takes too long** to create an entity manager(sometime 5 mins, sometime 20 mins.. randomly but too long) .

It gets stuck at EntityManager em = getFactory(id).createEntityManager(finalProps);  in EntityManagerCreator class.

it can be number of opened connections (?) - if the previous entity manager wasn't properly closed.. but I am doing it...

As my code is too long, so I created a demo program which is doing same things...below is my code but this is also behaving the same way...

```
public void cleanupRestorePoint(final String jobName, final String stepName) throws SQLException {
Map pmap = new HashMap();
pmap.put("javax.persistence.jdbc.url", "jdbc:oracle:thin:@XXXXX");
pmap.put("javax.persistence.jdbc.password", "aaaa");
pmap.put("javax.persistence.jdbc.user", "bbb");
EntityManagerFactory emf = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("JpaDm", pmap);

Connection connection = null;

EntityManager em = null;
try {

    em = emf.createEntityManager(pmap);

    connection = em.unwrap(Connection.class);
    Map<String, Object> properties = emf.getProperties();
    System.out.println("pro" + properties);


    EntityTransaction transaction = em.getTransaction();
    transaction.begin();
    //to do
    transaction.commit();

} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();

}finally{
    em.clear();
    em.close();
    emf.close();
}}
```

persistence.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence"
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" version="2.0"
   xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd">

   <persistence-unit name="JpaDm" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
      <provider>org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.PersistenceProvider</provider>
      <properties>

         <!-- This property is dynamically set from the application if the DataSource is configured  -->
         <!-- It will also overwrite the following 4 properties - the DB connection ones -->
         <!-- <property name="javax.persistence.nonJtaDataSource" value="java:/comp/env/jdbc/aaaa" /> -->

         <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver" />
         <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url" value="jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:orcl" />
         <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.user" value="aaaaa" />
         <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.password" value="vvvv" />

         <property name="eclipselink.target-database" 
               value="org.eclipse.persistence.platform.database.oracle.OraclePlatform"/>

         <!-- issues with Primitive collections validation -->
         <property name="javax.persistence.validation.mode" value="NONE" />
         <property name="eclipselink.session.customizer"
            value="com.bphx.adaprep.support.ELSessionCustomizer" />

         <!-- <property name="eclipselink.jdbc.batch-writing" value="JDBC"/> -->
         <property name="eclipselink.jdbc.batch-writing" value="oracle-jdbc" />
         <property name="eclipselink.jdbc.batch-writing.size" value="1000"/>

         <!-- Logging -->
         <property name="eclipselink.logging.level" value="WARNING" />
         <!-- property name="eclipselink.profiler" value="PerformanceProfiler"/ -->
         <property name="eclipselink.logging.timestamp" value="true" />
         <property name="eclipselink.logging.session" value="false" />
         <property name="eclipselink.logging.thread" value="false" />
         <property name="eclipselink.ddl-generation.output-mode" value="sql-script" />
         <!-- Needed to add custom indexes -->
         <!-- property name="javax.persistence.sql-load-script-source" value="META-INF/sqlinit.sql" /> -->
         <!-- UNCOMMENT FOR DDL GENERATION / DROP CREATE -->
         <!-- 
         <property name="eclipselink.ddl-generation" value="drop-and-create-tables" /> 
         <property name="eclipselink.application-location" value="dm" /> 
         <property name="eclipselink.create-ddl-jdbc-file-name" value="createDDL.jdbc" />
         <property name="eclipselink.drop-ddl-jdbc-file-name" value="dropDDL.jdbc" />
         <property name="eclipselink.ddl-generation.output-mode" value="both" / 
         -->

         <property name="eclipselink.session-event-listener" value="com.bphx.adaprep.config.ConverterInitializer" />

         <!-- Disable weaving - comment for production usage -->
         <property name="eclipselink.connection-pool.min" value="10"/>
         <property name="eclipselink.connection-pool.max" value="400"/>
         <property name="eclipselink.connection-pool.wait" value="100"/>
         <property name="eclipselink.weaving" value="false" />



      </properties>
   </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

Please let me know what are my options to stop its hanging..
if there are any leaked resources how can I check them? And this code is working fine on local but giving issue on Dev environment and I don't have 3rd environment to test it.

Comment: You are leaking connections. Also why are you doing this? Let Spring managed the EMF for you and simplify your code. You shouldn't be creating it over and over again.

Comment: yes I think so but how can I debug leaking connections? And I didn't get let Spring manage EMF, how can I do that..?

Comment: First, turn on EclipseLink log levels, and you'll quickly see that by creating and closing factories, this is putting an enormous drain on your system.  Each time it will scan through the persistence unit files to create/predeploy the persistence unit, and when the EM is created, finish deployment by creating the connections pools using settings you've provided.  You should be keeping your EMF alive statically and only closing it when the application is done to avoid recreating the same resources over and over.  The EMF is thread safe, EMs are not.